# Trouble reading parameter values from testng.xml

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I am having trouble reading parameter values from testng.xml inside a testng testcase in Eclipse IDE. I have browser initiated from BeforeClass and at @TEST method ,parameter values are coming as "NULL"...and it asks me to define my @Test parameters as Optional..

MyJavacode

```
public class headerValidation extends init {
    WebDriver driver;


@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {

    driver = initBrowser(BrowserType.FIREFOX, "http://www.abc123.com/");
        }

@Test
@Parameters(value = { "loginID", "PasswordKey", "testURL" } )
public void testLogin(String loginID, String PasswordKey, String testURL) throws Exception {

    try {

        driver.get(testURL);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-b")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_e")).sendKeys(loginID);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_p")).sendKeys(PasswordKey);
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();

    }//try

    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    
    }//catch
```

My Testng XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
    <test name="Test">
    <parameter name="loginID" value="emailadd@add2.com"></parameter>
    <parameter name="PasswordKey" value="21232131"></parameter>
    <parameter name="testURL" value="www.abctest.com"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="org.pa.qa.headerValidation"/>
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: How are you running your test?

Comment: Im running it as TESTng Test in eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the file and run as testng test, the testng xml is not picked up by default, which explains why the parameters are not being picked up.
Two solutions :

Right click on the suite xml and trigger with Run as ->testng suite

OR

Go to Project->Properties->Testng-> Set this xml as your template xml and then you can run as testng test

Comment: Thanks for the above info, I'm able to see parameters when explicitly running testng.xml file